# Advice to build a 2-step filtering system (brainstorming)

Tags: magento-1.8

we'd be pleased if somebody could borrow us some brain power to work out how to approach this.

We have a list of remote controls that work on different TV brands and models.
The client asked us to develop a page where people can select a TV manufacturer from a dropdown list. This, should then load another dropdown with a list of all related TV models, so that when one of this is selected, the correct remote control product page opens up.

So far, we created two multi-selectable attributes (manufacturers and models) and wrote a small module that loops each of the remote controls to build the manufacturer list. When one of the manufacturer is selected, the module loops through each product to find which one is related. Per each match found, we look at the other attribute (TV models) and we generate the second dropdown list.
when the user also selects the model, we send the ids of both manufacturer and model selected to loop again every product looking for the match. Finally, the remote controle of interest is opened up.

It works, however due to the large amount of products (the store has an overall of 8kk) the searching process can take up to 30 seconds - in particular when generating the models list.

What better approach would you suggest?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source the manufacturer and models out. Have a table for both, so you can search fast in it.

You are not interested in the relation between remote control and manufacturer. You are only interested in the relation between RC and model, so remove the attribute.

And to implement everything it might be an idea to implement a new eav attribute type, like date or price to handle everything.

The joins should be a lot faster than looking everything up in the table.

The frontend part is then just showing the tables, for the filtering you need only the ID of the RC.